# Apache access log shows inconsistent timezone

Tags: django, apache, timezone

I'm seeing lines like this in my apache access log:

```
10.195.39.199 - - [11/Oct/2017:18:28:55 -0500] "POST ...
10.195.39.199 - - [11/Oct/2017:18:28:57 -0500] "GET ...
10.195.39.199 - - [11/Oct/2017:18:29:00 -0500] "POST ...
10.195.39.199 - - [11/Oct/2017:18:29:08 -0500] "GET ...
192.17.24.32 - - [11/Oct/2017:23:29:27 +0000] "POST ...
192.17.24.32 - - [11/Oct/2017:23:29:27 +0000] "GET ...
192.17.24.32 - - [11/Oct/2017:18:38:10 -0500] "GET ...
192.17.24.32 - - [11/Oct/2017:18:38:49 -0500] "POST ...
```

The requests are all sequential in this order, yet the fifth and sixth lines show a UTC timestamp while all the rest show a timestamp with the correct local timezone.

What could be causing this?  I assume the errant lines are coming from an apache  worker thread that was somehow initialized with the wrong timezone information, but how would this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem turned out to be that I had two separate Django projects on the same host, each with its own settings file.  One was using Central time, and the other was using UTC.

Apparently that's the Wrong Way To Do It.  Instead you're supposed to have multiple Django *applications*, all living under the same *project*, sharing a single settings file.